# Weird image borders on mozilla firefox when sizing images

Tags: html, css, firefox

(link in revision history)

Notice some weird borders around schools like: USC (first row), W (third row)?

It doesn't happen in other browsers. I'm using Mozilla firefox 3.6.12.

Comment: I don't see nothing weird... FF3.6.12/Mac

Comment: Neither do I (FF4 Beta).

Comment: site advertisement? nothing wrong...

Comment: a lot of hours in front of your PC? take a break

Comment: Lots of spam votes on this question. I think in general, new users with low rep should avoid pasting links to their home page. Maybe take a screenshot of the affected area instead.

Comment: a screenshot would be very nice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it may be descender spacing. Try

```
td img { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be totally off cause I can't see the link... but, by any chance are you using Firefox under Ubuntu (not sure if it is general to Linux) and GIFs?

Because, recently I ran into this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/263661